# How to resolve this error getting with while running with grunt?

Tags: node.js, meanjs

I am tring to run MEANjs App which i cloned from meanjs github.

Currenty I am getting this error

[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5858
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1231:14)
    at listen (net.js:1267:10)
    at Agent.Server.listen (net.js:1363:5)
    at Object.start (_debug_agent.js:21:9)
    at startup (node.js:72:44)
    at node.js:933:3
```

Answer (score 2):

You're already listening on port 5858, either stop the process listening on that port or change your current app to use a different port.

So change your `server.listen()` to `server.listen(process.env.PORT || <someOtherPort>);`